# Problem with Numpy: Trying to simulate 1000 series of N amount of coin tosses

Tags: python, numpy

So what I'm trying to do is to calculate the odds of two series of coin tosses having the same number of heads. One of the requirements is that I do this by simulating 1000 series of N amount of coin tosses, where the user chooses how many coin tosses there are within 1 series. However, I'm running in to a problem with the simulation:

```
import numpy as np
user_series = int(input("How many series?"))
pairs = 0
tosses = 0
pair1_list = []
pair2_list = []
while tosses < 1000:
    pair1 = np.random.randint(1, 2, size = user_series)
    if pair1 == 1:
        pair1_list.append("H")
    elif pair1 == 2:
        pair1_list.append("T")
    pair2 = np.random.randint(1,2, size = user_series)
    if pair2 == 1:
        pair2_list.append("H")
    elif pair2 == 2:
        pair2_list.append("T")
    tosses += 1
print(pair1_list)
print(pair2_list)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I'm assuming there is a problem with the if statement(s), but I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: I believe the problem is that `pair_1` is an array of size user_series thus, `pair1 == 1` does not really work. see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: The error states that when you compare an array with a single value, the result is a list of each element compared to the single value, so the result is an _array_ of bools (one for each original element).  This works just fine, but if you then try to use it as a single bool (`if ...`) then this is unclear and it proposes to use `.any()` or `.all()` to make clear what you want.

Comment: I think you want to use `randint(0, 2)` to get 0s and 1s.

Comment: I think you want to _count_ the 1s and compare the results, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to calculate (roughly) how likely it is that both lists of tosses have an equal amount of Hs. How would I go about having the user pick the amount of coin tosses in a series?

Answer (score 1):

`np.random.randint(1, 2, size=5)` returns `array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])`. You cannot really compare array of length `user_series` with a single value `1` or `2`.

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Note that also according to documentation `high` is defined as

> ... one above the largest (signed) integer ...

so `np.random.randint(1, 2, size=5)` will return only `1`'s.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import numpy as np
user_series = int(input("How many series?"))
pairs = 0
tosses = 0
pair1_list = []
pair2_list = []
while tosses < 1000:
    pair1 = np.random.randint(1, 2, size = user_series)
    if pair1 == 1:
        pair1_list.append("H")
    elif pair1 == 2:
        pair1_list.append("T")
    pair2 = np.random.randint(1,2, size = user_series)
    if pair2 == 1:
        pair2_list.append("H")
    elif pair2 == 2:
        pair2_list.append("T")
    tosses += 1
    return tosses
print(pair1_list)
print(pair2_list)
```